# Ul LI Menu not displaying as Block in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-lists

I have a menu that displays properly in Firefox and Chrome, in IE8 it displays as a vertical list rather than a horizontal menu.

I am not sure why this is not working.
I have a doctype, and I am linking to the html5 js via google.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your time.

**CSS:**

```
#tools {position: absolute; top: -23px; right: 7px; font-size: 0.75em;} 
#tools li {list-style:none; display: inline-block; padding: 0px 10px; border-left: 1px solid #e8e4d8; line-height: 1; margin: 0;}
#tools li:first-child {padding-left: 0; border-left: 0;}
#tools a {color: #e8e4d8; line-height: 1; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 1px 0; display: block; text-decoration: none;}
#tools a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
```

**HTML:**

Note: not sure why but I am having a hard time displaying the `div` that starts here. so before the `ul` is a `div` id "tools"

```
< div id="tools" >         
<ul>
    <li><a href="">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">link</a></li>
    <li id="last_tool"><a href="">link</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried writting `<div id="tools">` without the blank spaces?

Comment: Try adding `#tools ul {list-style:none; display: inline-block;}`

Comment: @Agustin, the blank spaces are actually because for some reason I was having trouble displaying the div here, it kept changing the ul code to a list even though I was using the <pre> tag...Thanks tho! It looks like all I needed to do was add float:left on the list item!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set float: left on to the list item:

```
#tools li {list-style:none; display: inline-block; padding: 0px 10px; border-left: 1px solid #e8e4d8; line-height: 1; margin: 0; float: left;}
```